# change tableHeaderView frame, tableview's contentSize increase 0.5 every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I change the UITableView with following code,

```
CHANGE_FRAME_HEIGHT(header, CGRectGetMaxY(_lbFollowing.frame)+8)
_tableView.tableHeaderView= header;
```

but the tableivew's contentSize increase 0.5 every i call those code

```
2015-11-17 12:30:41.881 yueban[42934:3092288] -[UserInfoHeaderView layoutSelfView] [Line 245] <UITableView: 0x61d00023e680; frame = (0 0; 320 519); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000298610>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6030002737c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 474.00299978256226}>
<UserInfoHeaderView: 0x6160001d8880; frame = (0 0; 320 246.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x603000272f50>>

2015-11-17 12:30:41.903 yueban[42934:3092288] -[UserInfoHeaderView layoutSelfView] [Line 247] <UITableView: 0x61d00023e680; frame = (0 0; 320 519); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000298610>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6030002737c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 474.50299978256226}>
```

why ??

Comment: please provide code where did you add "lbFollowing"

Comment: @Jamil `CHANGE_FRAME_HEIGHT` is a marco I defined to get the correct frame, has nothing to do with the question. and I had find the solution and post the answer, Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer. I need call  `reloadData` after reset the `tableHeaderView`

```
_tableView.tableHeaderView=self;
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Flowing  code should be called  once in **viewDidLoad** method.

I think, your code is right, but not in right position.

```
CHANGE_FRAME_HEIGHT(header, CGRectGetMaxY(_lbFollowing.frame)+8);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

Comment: I know. but my header frame may be changed when user edit the content in other view. so I need to refresh it once the view appear